# How to use the same ViewController for tabs in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need to have two different tabs for one UIViewController.
I implement UITabBarController programmatically.

Code below works like show me two different tabs, but when I select firstVC it has black screen, secondVC is good.

How can I use two different tabs for same ViewConetroller?

```
class VPTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myWebView = WebKitViewController.storyboardInstance()

        let mainVC = MainViewController.storyboardInstance()
        mainVC?.tabBarItem.title = "Search"
        mainVC?.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named:"search")

        let firstVC = myWebView
        firstVC?.source = "first"
        let accountNavigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC!)
        accountNavigationVC.tabBarItem.title = "First"
        accountNavigationVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named:"first")

        let secondVC = myWebView
        secondVC?.source = "second"
        let myTripsNavigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC!)
        myTripsNavigationVC.tabBarItem.title = "Second"
        myTripsNavigationVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named:"Second")

        let viewControllerList = [ mainVC, firstVC, secondVC ]

        viewControllers = viewControllerList as? [UIViewController]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can hack it by creating two wrapper view controllers, that would contain in the view nothing else, just the `myWebView`'s view that you want to have on both tabs. Now create two instances of this wrapper, that would both include the same `myWebView` as a subview.

Now you have to remember that the same view cannot be a subview of two different views (it can have only one superview). By adding the `myWebView.view` as a subview to a wrapper removes it from its previous superview. Therefore, you have to listen to tab changes in order to re-add it when a wrapper gets presented (each time a wrapper is presented, you have to add `myWebView` as a subview to the presented wrapper).